# Mobile and Tablet IDs differ & in some case few IDs does not appear in case of mobile, suggest a logic to be used in testing

Tags: selenium, appium, ui-automation

I'm working on android app automation using appium, as per business requirement both UI (Mobile & tablet) differ(70%) from each other. Due to this some extra controls are appearing for the tablet but not for mobile and in some cases, ID or XPath also differ for both devices for the same element.
Example:

```
By headerNameTablet = By.id("com.android.appname:id/header_title");

By headerNameMobile = By.id("com.android.appname:id/titleView");
```

I'm differentiating between mobile and tablet after login into the app using my script (using selenium and JAVA) and storing text "Mobile" or "Tablet" in a global variable name DEVICETYPE.

Considering above scenarios, please suggest how I can write a test method so that at the runtime required ID or XPath is called. If I'll use 'if else' condition then it would be very complicated to maintain the code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simple answer, stop using id based locators, try to use xpath or cssSelector which are based on relative position to webelements.

Comment: Its native application not hybrid one. it is possible to user relative xpath in this case.. ? what about those element which appears only incase of tablet but will not appear in case of mobile. Could you explain more in this regards. Thanks!

Comment: for those attributes which only appear for one sort of device you can handle them in try..catch block and relative xpath should work.

Answer (score 0):

If both mobile and tablet will be having the same text content, use `By.name("your text")`